# How can the only maximal ideal of $C[x] / X^2$ be $(X)$?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, proof-explanation

In my notes I have the following example which I don't understand.

> Let $f$ be the canonical injection from $C$ to $C[X]/X^2$.The only maximal ideal of $C[X]/X^2$ is $(X)$ and $f^{-1}((X))$=$(0)$.

What I don't understand are the following what does $f$ do? It takes an element $p$ in $C$ and assigns it to $p+(X^2)$? And how can the maximal ideal of $C[X]/X^2$ be $(X)$? Elements of the former are cosets and elements of the latter are polynomials.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're right: the maximal ideal of $C[X]/(X^2)$  is $(X)/(X^2)$.

Comment: You're right about what f does. The notation (X) means the ideal generated by the element X + (X^2) in C[X]/X^2. It is common to refer to this element as simply 'X' rather than the coset 'X + (X^2)'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only maximal ideal of $C[X]/X^2$ is the image of the ideal $(X) \subset C[X]$ in $C[X]/X^2.$ It is normally written as the ideal generated by $X + (X^2)$ or simply $(\bar X)$ where $\bar X$ denotes the image of $X$ in $C[X]/X^2$ (under the canonical projection). Sometimes people just write $(X)$ in $C[X]/X^2$ if there is no confusion. But one should keep in mind that it means *"the image of the ideal $(X) \subset C[X]$ in $C[X]/X^2.$"*

Answer (score 1):

(1) You have the definition of $f$ right. You could think of it as the composition
$$
\mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{C}[X] \to \mathbf{C}[X]/(X^2)
$$
where the first map is the inclusion of $\mathbf{C}$ as scalar polynomials and the second is the quotient map.

(2) This is a common abuse: It's annoying to have to write $X + (X^2)$, $\overline{X}$, or give a name to the quotient map, so one instead refers to the image of $X$ in $\mathbf{C}[X]/(X^2)$ as $X$ again and hopes that no confusion results — unfortunately for the beginner, it inevitably does. Given this, is it clear why $(X)$ is the unique maximal ideal of this quotient?

Comment: well what I am thinking is that if a poly has each monomial greater degree than 1 then (p)/($X^2$) is just the identity and if p has a scalar then is C[X]/X^2. So the maximal ideal must be generated by X.Is that correct?

Comment: Let me try to translate what you've said: if $p \in \mathbf{C}[X]$ then we can look at the ideal it generates in the quotient. If $p(X) = a_0 + a_1X + a_2X^2 + \cdots$ then modulo $X^2$ it is congruent to $a_0 + a_1X$, so we can narrow our view. If $a_0 \neq 0$ then you should be able to produce an invertible for $p$ modulo $X^2$ — what is it? So we're left with $a_1X$, $a_1 \neq 0$, generating the only nontrivial ideal, and of course it's okay to take $a_1 = 1$. I suppose one should justify that the quotient is nonzero and that $(X)$ isn't the whole ring.

Comment: But another way to view it, and this is probably the right idea, is to use the isomorphism theorem that says that ideals of $R/I$ and ideals of $R$ containing $I$ correspond in a way that preserves primality and maximality. Then figure out what the maximal ideals of $\mathbf{C}[X]$ containing $X^2$ are. This is not so hard: if a maximal ideal of $\mathbf{C}[X]$ contains $X^2$ then it must contain $X$, and $(X)$ is already seen to be maximal.